# Python program execution order

Tags: python-3.6

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math

a = float(input('a = '))
b = float(input('b = '))
c = float(input('c = '))

def quadratic(a, b ,c):
    delta = b**2 - 4*a*c
    if delta < 0:
        print('There is no real root for this equation')
    else:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
        print('The root for this equation are: x1 =', x1, '; x2 =', x2)

    return x1, x2

quadratic(a, b, c)
```

When I input a = 3, b =2, c =3, I got that:

```
~/file $ ./quadratic.py 
a = 3
b = 2
c = 3
There is no solution for this equation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./quadratic.py", line 19, in <module>
    quadratic(a, b, c)
  File "./quadratic.py", line 17, in quadratic
    return x1, x2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x1' referenced before assignment
```

In my opinion, I thought the program should execute until print('There is no real root ... equation') and then jump to the line (return x1, x2).
And I have search UnboundLocalError in python documentation. But I didn't
use variable x1 outside the function. So I can't understand how the error
comes out. And I think maybe an error(NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
) is more reasonable.

Comment: It is doing exactly what you say, except when you attempt to `return x1, x2` they are undefined. As the error states, you can't reference unassigned variables, which you are attempting to do when `return`ing them.

Comment: Note that you should also deal with the linear case; when `a` is 0.

Comment: @Phylogenesis When I deleted assignments in else block, I ran the program again and got an error(NameError: name 'x1' is not defined ). When I input (a = 3, b = 2, c = 3), the program wouldn't run the else block. I don't know why the different error came out.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you for your prompt.